# Trying to create a password-protected PFX file results in openssl error: "

Tags: azure, ssl, openssl

## Background

- We have MS Azure cloud hosting
- Purchased a wildcard SSL certificate for my domain from a 3rd party (not Microsoft)
- Created a CSR file + private key file
- Used these & have been issued **x509** and **PKCS7** certs from SSL issuer
- Azure requires a PFX file, so have been attempting to follow the ssl.com tutorial here: https://www.ssl.com/how-to/create-a-pfx-p12-certificate-file-using-openssl/

### Issue

Running the openssl command in terminal on my local machine (breaks inserted for readability)

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -password pass:somepassword
-inkey domain.key -in certificate.crt
```

I receive the following error:

```
140735704675208:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22/libressl/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:704:
Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

But I've supplied the key? I'm confused. I'm an SSL beginner when it comes to Azure. What am I doing wrong?

*Note, I included the -password parameter because MS Azure expects PFX files to be password protected. This is not optional: they HAVE to be protected.*

## EDIT

Having regenerated a CSR & Key using Openssl, I get a new error that the key file isn't valid. To ensure I'm not missing something obvious:

- What do I do with the X509?
- What do I do with the PKCS7?

Comment: I have just typed your command in my own comodo certs and it worked. Pleas check the pem files (the key with **openssl rsa -in domain.key  -check**, and modulus from crt and key should match **openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | openssl md5** and, for the key **openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in domain.key | openssl md5**)

Comment: Thank you @J.M.Robles - I followed those steps:

`openssl rsa -in domain.key -check`

results in

`unable to load Private Key`

`140735704675208:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22/libressl/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:704:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY`

Comment: Well, there are problems with your domain.key file. Please, edit it to check if it is a good pem file and, if so, if the key is encrypted or not (first line). Mine is not encrypted (-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----).

Comment: @J.M.Robles - my .key file starts/ends with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- / -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Should it not?

Comment: Encrypted keys begin with -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----. Your file is not (neither mine). Please test if lines end with \r\n (in my file they ends with  \n) and try using other implementation of openssl (other OS).

Comment: For completeness, I regenerated CSR & Private Key via an updated openssl on my machine. I validated the Key file using your command. It worked.

Except now, when I try my original command (`openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -password pass:somepassword -inkey domain.key -in certificate.crt`) I get a new error: `"No certificate matches private key"`

I truly have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: Cert and key must match. You can check it with the modulus command.  **openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | openssl md5**  and, **openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in domain.key | openssl md5**

Answer (score 0):

Got bored messing about with openssl and terminal so found a GUI to do it. Steps:

- Copy X509 contents, paste into code editor, save as cert.pem
- Copy private key, paste into code editor, save as private.key
- Go to https://help.configuressl.com/ssl-tools/ssl-converter/, upload both
- Set password
- Export as PFX

This generates a password protected PFX which can then be uploaded to Azure.